# 3d vectors - transform and minus

Tags: c++, stl

Can std::transform be used in a nested way? Tried to do this:

```
                    {
                        return std::transform(asciivec(inner.front()).begin(), asciivec(inner.front()).end(), asciivec(inner.back()).begin(), asciivec(inner.back()).end(),out.begin(), std::minus<float>{});
                    }
                   );
```

```
Error: 
stl_algo.h||In instantiation of '_OIter std::transform(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter, _UnaryOperation) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*, std::vector<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >; _OIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> >; _UnaryOperation = main()::<lambda(const auto:1&)>]':|


error: no matching function for call to 'transform(std::vector<double>::iterator, std::vector<double>::iterator, std::vector<double>::iterator, std::vector<double>::iterator, std::vector<double>::iterator, std::minus<float>)'|
```

Comment: The best way is to start writing some code.

Comment: @PaulEvans Looking for a cleaner way to do other than the naive method. Not sure if it can be done using std::transform as there are multiple vectors.

Comment: I believe std::minus<float> should be std::minus<float>{}

Comment: Typo in the question. Fixed it.

Comment: Your inner transform has too many parameters.  Give some additional though to what it is that transform is supposed to be doing, and then how it should be doing that - one dimension at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track, but you missed a few things.

- For binary operations, `std::transform` only takes both begin and end iterators for the first input range; it takes a begin iterator for the second range, and assumes the second range is at least as large as the first (such that for any element in the range `[first1, last1)`, there's a matching element in the range starting at `first2`).
- Assuming that `asciivec()` returns a temporary object (and not a reference to a cached object), the iterators `asciivec(inner.front()).begin()` and `asciivec(inner.front()).end()` will actually refer to two different ranges; this will cause runtime errors.  You'll need to cache the results of your `asciivec()` calls inside the lambda, to give them enough permanence to finish the operation.
- `std::minus` evaluates its operands as `lhs - rhs`, and thus will return `-1` for `std::minus<float>{}('a', 'b')`.  As your example results are positive, I have assumed you want absolute values, and have expanded & commentated my code thusly.

So, considering that, we can make a few slight alterations...

```
// Renamed "inner" to "in" for convenience here.
std::transform (inp.cbegin(), inp.cend(), out.begin(), [&](const auto& in)
    {
        // Tying element type to asciivec() for convenience.
        using Container = decltype(asciivec(in.front()));
        using      Elem = typename Container::value_type;
        //using Elem = typename decltype(asciivec(in.front()))::value_type;

        // Create non-temporary vectors first, to guarantee expected results.
        std::vector<Container> inner = { asciivec(in.front()), asciivec(in.back()) };

        // Use either...
        // static Container ret;
        // ret.clear(); ret.resize(inner.front().size());
        // Or...
        Container ret(inner.front().size());

        std::transform(inner.front().begin(),          // InputIt first1
                       inner.front().end(),            // InputIt last1
                       inner.back().begin(),           // InputIt first2
                       //asciivec(inner.back()).end(), // Omit
                       ret.begin(),                    // OutputIt d_first
                       std::minus<float>{});           // BinaryOperation binary_op

        // I'm positive you want absolute values. ;3
        // Lambda provides nice, clean overload resolution, compared to a function pointer or similar.
        std::transform(ret.begin(), ret.end(), ret.begin(), [=](const Elem& e) { return std::fabs(e); });

        return ret;
    }
);
```

If signedness is, in fact, desired, we can comment out the second `transform()` call.

See it in action [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8e3d1d60a80ea3c).

<sup>Edited to increase genericity, it should be fine to just drop in regardless of your data's actual types.</sup>